# react & web pack hot loader. "waiting for roots to load...to reload the inspector"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Just updated react to 0.13.3 and now I get the following message in Chrome react developer tool: `"waiting for roots to load...to reload the inspector"` and a button saying "click here".

And if I click the button, same thing again.

FYI: I am using WebPack & webpack-dev-server.

Have you seen this?

Comment: you might want to try the beta of the new version of React devtools: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/releases, it's a huge improvement.

Comment: Chromes extension for Reacts devtools is regularly updated, that shouldn't be the issue

Answer (score 6):

This error is generally linked to modules not loading into the project correctly, but the cause of this when the react syntax is incorrect. Generally, it's a missing semicolon after return statements (easy to miss).

I've confirmed this using [reacts tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), writing it out myself, seeing this error, then commenting mine out and replacing it with the script including example.js

Comment: Yeah fixing my syntax and then reinstalling node modules worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Updating my loader worked:

module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: /.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
  ]
}

Comment: Where is the config for the loaders located?

Comment: If you're using webpack, it's located in webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports and exports of each of your component files. I had this same error because I forgot to export a component to my index.js file.