# Building React.js for production, built with gulp, browserify, babelify

Tags: reactjs, npm, gulp, browserify

I have problem to build React project in production, without babel file.
Per [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html), for production it's only required to have React and ReactDom scripts. Everything works fine in development. I just need to remove babel core script in production, and when I do that I get this error message:

> Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev
>   environment for the full error message and additional helpful
>   warnings.

These are included scripts

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Remove this in production -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

<script src="build/all.min.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Here is my Gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const browserify = require('browserify');
const babelify = require('babelify');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const streamify = require('gulp-streamify');


gulp.task('default', () => {
    return browserify('main.js')
        .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(streamify(concat('all.min.js')))
        .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('build', () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
    gulp.start('default');
});
```

Comment: Try using the non-minified versions of React and ReactDOM in your production version. They will throw more useful errors, which you can use to figure out what's breaking.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have new message from React's console: "Waiting for roots to load...to reload the inspector" I think bundle script should be changed to text/javascript in production, right? If so, I get this in browser's console: "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react & web pack hot loader. "waiting for roots to load...to reload the inspector"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359652/react-web-pack-hot-loader-waiting-for-roots-to-load-to-reload-the-inspecto)