# Hot reloading making debugging impossible

Tags: google-chrome, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app

I generated a react app using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which comes with some sort of hot reloading feature. Apparently, when I save a file the browser should reload the page. This only works some of the time. Whenever I make a change, I see this:

[image]

I see this same thing when I manually reload as well. I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome on macOS Sierra

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome. See if the error occurs in another version of Chrome (portable or canary).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react & web pack hot loader. "waiting for roots to load...to reload the inspector"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359652/react-web-pack-hot-loader-waiting-for-roots-to-load-to-reload-the-inspecto)